# Inserting data in one table based on another in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below query..What I am doing is after inserting in one table I am getting the ColumnID and then inserting it in another table..I have about 100 rows..Is there a better way of doing this or do I need to repeat the same query 100 times.

```
DECLARE @rowId INT

INSERT INTO bookFee (
    Amount
    ,UnitID
    ,Quantity
    ,QuantityUnitID
    ,FeeID
    ,bookID
    ,CurrencyID
    ,PriceTypeID
    ,IsMinimum
    ,IsVariable
    ,ServiceID
    ,MarkupPct
    ,IsBundled
    ,MarginPct
    ,Cost
    )
VALUES (
    NULL
    ,16
    ,NULL
    ,38
    ,NULL
    ,47
    ,1
    ,1
    ,0
    ,0
    ,3
    ,NULL
    ,1
    ,0.10
    ,45.0000
    )

SET @rowId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO bookFeeBandValue (
    bookFeeID
    ,bookBandID
    ,Value
    )
VALUES (
    @rowId
    ,395
    ,3.5833
    )
```

Comment: What's wrong with `rollback`?

Comment: `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` then `ROLLBACK;` . If your question is to rollback something which has already been committed, then I hope you've got Backups because it's not possible.

Comment: So what I am basically trying to do is after every insert statement in the BookFee table I need to get the bookFeeID identity column and then make another insert into the FeeBandValue table..There are about 100 rows so I was thinking if there is any way to do it in a couple of statements rather than writing insert first then getting rowId then another insert and same for 100 rows

Comment: Change your question then, because Rollback is not what you are looking for. Write the problem, don't try to figure out a solution.

Comment: You should look into using the OUTPUT clause in your insert statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Comment: Yeah I think I made it confusing when it was a simple question

Comment: Changed the question to make it simple.

Comment: @user1221989 look at the URL Sean Lange has provided, that is the answer to your question. Output the IDs to a temp table, then you can access them in the same transaction and insert them into your table.

Comment: where does your input data comes from ? It looks like you have to do the first insert 100 times anyway